# Powershell - Select-Object - Export-Csv removes object delimiter(,) from JSON

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I am storing the content of a JSON output into a variable and the by using:

```
$j1| Select - Object -Property @{Label = "id"; Expression = {$_.id} | Export-CSV -Path C:\Temp\j1.csv -Delimiter "|" -notype
```

I am exporting the values to csv file.

My issue is that inside the PowerShell, I can see e.g.

```
{1}
{2,3}
{4}
{5,6}
```

However, after exporting to csv, the comma delimiter of object is missing. And I would like to have in csv too.

Could you please help me with my problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you would add a sample 'JSON output' and the powershell code you are having problems with (I'm guessing the latter is the code you have posted already), it would be easier to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have arrays as properties when you export to CSV. You need to join the IDs to a string before exporting it. Ex:

```
Select-Object -Property @{Label="id";Expression={$_.id -join ','}
```